# cant connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

Fawad-PC = my pc name (windows)
i deleted my mysql server coz i install xampp too there were 2 same databases with me. so when ever i try to login to my app its connecting to the 1 in mysql server and not in xampp one so i un install mysql server but the process was too slow and cant terminate so i restart my windows after that i check programs and features and mysql server were not there so i came to my app and when i try 2 login i got this wiered error

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'Fawad-PC' is
not allowed to connect to this MySQL server' in D:\SVN data\WebClient_PHP\trunk\library
\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php:129
```

can any one tell what is this error.my app was running very nice but today i dont know how when i enter my password its showing this error

```
  Stack trace:

 #0 D:\SVN data\Phoggi_WebClient_PHP\trunk\phoggi\library\Zend\Db\Adapter
\Pdo\Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=192....', 'root', 'root', Array) 

#1 D:\SVN data\Phoggi_WebClient_PHP\trunk\phoggi\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php 
(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()

#2 D:\SVN data\Phoggi_WebClient_PHP\trunk\phoggi\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php
(860): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()

#3 D:\SVN data\Phoggi_WebClient_PHP\trunk\phoggi\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php
(930): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote('123', NULL) 

 #4 D:\SVN data\Phoggi_WebClient_PHP\trunk\phoggi\library\Zend\Auth\Adapter\DbTable.php
(449): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quoteInto('`user_password`...', '123') #5 D:\SVN data 
\Phoggi_WebClient_PHP\trunk\phoggi\library\Zend\Aut in D:\SVN data\Phoggi_WebClient_PHP
 \trunk\phoggi\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 144
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the small piece of the connection string visible in the stack trace, I see the mysql server host is an IP address.

If this newly installed MySQL server is on the same PC that is running Apache, then try changing the host to `localhost` instead of the IP address.

If you are trying to connect to a MySQL server on another PC, then you will have to add a user that is allowed to connect from a remote host.

Examples:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'Fawad-PC' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';  // can connect from Fawad-PC
```

or

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';  // can connect from ANYWHERE
```

Then you will have to grant privileges on a specific database to that user:

```
GRANT ALL on database.* to 'user'@'Fawad-PC'
```

Try changing the MySQL host to localhost first though, I think that will solve your problem.